# Apache Lucene createFullTextQuery returns null object as matched

Tags: java, lucene, full-text-search, hibernate-search

My following Lucene query

```
org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = qb.bool() 
            .should(qb.keyword().onField("name").matching(searchString.toLowerCase()).createQuery()).createQuery();
        result= getFullTextEntityManager().createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Verb.class).setProjection(ProjectionConstants.THIS, ProjectionConstants.SCORE).setMaxResults(1).getResultList();
```

returns: [null, 6.170484] for searchString 'mix'

This is the first time I have observed a null being returned as a match instead of the matched instance.

Following is the annotation on my Verb.class

```
@Field(analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.YES, termVector=TermVector.YES)
private String name;
```

Any one has any idea?

TIA

**EDIT**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="mverb")
@Indexed
public class Verb extends Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  @Field(analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.YES, termVector=TermVector.YES)
  private String name;

}
```

On Application load

```
indexAllVerbs();
searchVerbs("mix");
```

Functions:

```
protected FullTextEntityManager getFullTextEntityManager() {
        return Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);
}

public void indexAllVerbs() {
    for (Verb b : Foo.getVerbs()) {
        getFullTextEntityManager().index(b);
    }
}

public List<Object[]> searchVerbs(String searchString) {
    QueryBuilder qb = getFullTextEntityManager().getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Verb.class).get();
    org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = qb.bool() 
            .should(qb.keyword().onField("name").matching(searchString.toLowerCase()).createQuery()).createQuery();
    return getFullTextEntityManager().createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Verb.class).setProjection(ProjectionConstants.THIS, ProjectionConstants.SCORE).setMaxResults(1).getResultList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It most likely means that the identifier extracted from the matching document does not match any entity in the database.

Two possible reasons for that:

1. You're using an exotic field bridge on your ID, and it does not work well. Check your implementation.
2. Your index is out of sync for some reason. [Reindex your database](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-batchindex).

Comment: Thanks Yoann, I call getFullTextEntityManager.index() just before the search operation. I executed several search operations with different query strings. But it consistently fails with 'mix', whereas it gives correct result with other queries. Could the indexed key word length being too small be an issue perhaps? Inconsistent behavior is making me question why this particular entity 'mix' returns as null whereas others are working fine.

Comment: @user2745862 Please provide the full code, including the call to getFullTextEntityManager.index(). Generally calling .index() is not needed, so you must be doing something strange.

Comment: Yoann, I wouldn't be surprised to learn if I am doing something strange. Please find the code above. Thanks for your help

Comment: @user2745862 What about your `Foo.getVerbs()`? Are you 100% positive it returns already persisted entities? Entities that have been flushed to the database? Can you see those entities in the database? I'm asking because, you know, it's hardly common practice to return entities from a static method...

Comment: Yoann, I just wrote Foo.getVerbs() for ease of understanding, its basically my repository service which queries the DB and get persisted Verb List. Verb Entity is anyways a library, and I do not update entries in that table so there is no question of unflushed data. Has to be something else. Thanks

Comment: @user2745862 I don't know... You might want to use the debug mode to see what's going on in `org.hibernate.search.query.hibernate.impl.ProjectionLoader#load(org.hibernate.search.query.engine.spi.EntityInfo)`, or submit a simple reproducer and we'll have a look. One last change you can try: use a proper MassIndexer instead of your `index` loop: `getFullTextEntityManager().createIndexer().startAndWait();`